# mysql procedure

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS
`ufdc_sales`.`depot_stack_register3_7_2` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `enter code here`
`depot_stack_register3_7_2`( IN stackId BIGINT,IN speciesId 
BIGINT,IN fromdate DATE,IN todate DATE)
BEGIN
set @mysql='select  sdt.depot_lot_no

from stack st , stock_detail_trans  sdt 

where sdt.stack_id=st.id 
      SET @mysql = @mysql+' AND st.SPECIES_ID='+1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Error in append. I want to know how can I add this query.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com :-) What is your question? Where do you want to "add" your query to? Please be more specific.

Comment: can you explain more about `add this query`? select statement doesn't have `set` clause.

Comment: Educated guess: you get a precise syntax error message you've carefully omitted, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
SET @mysql='select  sdt.depot_lot_no
            from stack st , stock_detail_trans  sdt 
            where sdt.stack_id=st.id';
SET @mysql = CONCAT(@mysql, ' AND st.SPECIES_ID = 1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Quotes come in pairs. Instead of:

```
set @mysql='select  sdt.depot_lot_no
from stack st , stock_detail_trans  sdt 
where sdt.stack_id=st.id 
      SET @mysql = @mysql+' AND st.SPECIES_ID='+1;
```

... try:

```
set @mysql='select  sdt.depot_lot_no
    from stack st , stock_detail_trans  sdt 
    where sdt.stack_id=st.id ';
SET @mysql = @mysql+' AND st.SPECIES_ID='+1;
```

And please don't ignore error messages. They're here to help you!